# Rigged figure in one Blender file - when append to another Blender file, it shows Armature but cannot animate

Tags: armature, append

First off, I have appended a number of other rigged objects via 'Collections' to Blender files before and they worked as expected. I fact, this human figure was appended before. But, during the course of editing it in project appended into, I made a mess in a variety of ways, including not being about to unhide the armature. So deleted it and appended the figure again. Basically, I am in the same situation as before in that I see in the Outliner the armature, but cannot select it.

Comment: Are you certain you appended it and didn't link it?

Comment: I am sure. I did try linking and had a similar result.

Comment: I see now that two other figures that I appended to this project file, these though had their cyclic animation done previous to appending, also don't allow me to see/select the bones.

I opened an old version of the project file and appended the figure with no problems.

It appears that it's a project file issue/setting and not the figure itself or the process of appending it.

Any ideas what setting is causing this global elimination of access to bones?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it was simply that the Bones box wasn't checked in the Viewport Overlay.
At least it wasn't something truly disastrous... just a simple oversight.